# Extracting environmental variables at coordinates

Tags: r, environment-variables, coordinates, extract, spatial

I am using R and trying to create a dataframe containing information on environmental variables at coordinates (x,y).

Currently I am working with a matrix with altitude data. It is in the form `long, lat, altitude`.

And a spatial points data frame containing my x,y coordinates

I have tried to use the extract function in the form:

```
xyalts <- extract(altvals,xypoints)
```

however I keep getting the error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘extract’ for signature ‘"matrix", "SpatialPointsDataFrame"’
```

Can anyone suggest why this would not work? Can the extract function not be used for spatial point data frames?

Comment: `extract` from the **raster** package expects argument 'x' (i.e., altvals) to be a 'Raster*' object. Therefore, you are required to transform the matrix to a proper 'RasterLayer' object using `raster` before running `extract`.

Comment: thank you! had hoped I could extract from matrix but went with extracting from rastor @fdetsch